# Is the set of prime numbers not Dedekind infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading Patrick Suppe's Axiomatic Set Theory, and in the book, he defines a Dedekind infinite set as a set who is equipollent to at least one of its proper subsets.

With this, I tried to think of a set that was not Dedekind infinite. After thinking about it for a while I thought about the primes and concluded that the primes are not Dedekind infinite. My argument goes like this:

let $P$ be the set of prime numbers and $N$ be the set of natural numbers, then $P\subset N$.

Euler had already proved that there is no general formula that will take a natural input and give a prime output for all $n\in N$.

because $P\subset N$, $p\in N$.

this can be used to show that the primes are not closed under the standard arithmetic operations (perhaps this was a bit of a leap of logic, but I'm not looking to rigorously prove this).

If the primes are not closed under these operations and there is no general formula that will output primes given a natural, then we can say that there is no 1-1 correspondence on the primes to one of its subsets and it is therefore not Dedekind infinite.

This argument may be horrendous as I'm just learning set theory, but I'll accept any critiques. Also, stating that the primes were not closed under the standard arithmetic operations may have been redundant as this may have been implied by the lack of a general form. any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: The primes are in $1:1$ correspondence with the odd primes, under the map $p_i\mapsto p_{i+1}$, where $p_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ prime.

Comment: Should say:  Euler showed that there was no polynomial with integer coefficients that had only prime values  for integer arguments.  That's not the same as saying that he proved that there was no formula...indeed there are such formulas though the ones that are known are hardly useful.  Basically they just encode some simple sieve.  Some relevant formulas can be found, e.g., [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a chance you could provide an example of a non-Dedekind infinite set?

Comment: However, the primes are well ordered since the naturals are, and their order type under the natural ordering will have to be $\omega$; we don't need to know anything about the arithmetic definability of such an injection.

Comment: I edited my earlier comment to include a link to some prime generating formulas.  That site should also contain useful references.  I'm sorry to say I've forgotten how to constructed infinite Dedekind-finite sets.  If memory serves, you can do it in ZF if you do not assume  choice.

Comment: [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1957.pdf) is a useful reference.

Comment: In ZFC (the usual set theory axioms, including choice), all infinite sets are also Dedekind infinite.  If AC doesn't hold, you can have infinite sets that are Dedekind finite.

Comment: Jacob, you cannot exhibit directly any infinite sets that are not Dedekind infinite. When the other comments say that you can have such sets, what this means is that it is consistent with ZF, the usual axioms of set theory (without the axiom of choice), that such sets exist. That is, if ZF is consistent at all, then there are models of ZF where the statement that there is such a set holds. The usual example of such a model is usually called Cohen's first model.

Comment: I haven't gotten to the chapter on the axiom of choice, so this next question is based on my limited knowledge of it, but can you define a set that isn't Dedekind infinite using the axiom of choice? Also, what's the difference between a transfinite cardinal and an infinite cardinal? If the axioms just state that such a set can exist, but we have no example what would there be to differentiate between the two? Or is the fact that such a set can exist considered reason enough to have distinguishable names? Sorry if these aren't great questions.

Comment: @JacobHulse Choice doesn't help - the axiom of choice implies that every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite. Infinite Dedekind-finite sets are a pathology which can only occur *without* choice. "Transfinite" and "infinite" are synonymous in all contexts I'm aware. And yes, this is a situation where a property is interesting enough that it warrants a name even if it has no concrete examples.